# Java script check on click script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to on click of a yes radio button to fire off a check on a checkbox. It is not working though.

```
 $("#ctl00_ctl39_g_b36986cf_3dae_456d_938c_3e398e9272e8_ff111_ctl00_ctl00").click(function(){
 $("#ctl00_ctl39_g_b36986cf_3dae_456d_938c_3e398e9272e8_ff101_ctl00_ctl02").check=true;
```

Am I missing something easy here?

Thanks

Comment: have tried .checked=true also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Am I missing something easy here?

Yes, you are. `.check = true` isn't how jQuery works.

You need to use `.prop('checked', true)`.

Comment: I guess I should have asked how to uncheck it with No button. I see .prop(checked,false)option but it breaks things when i duplicate the code above with the no radio button and the false attribute.